# ActiveMQ Artemis AMQ229031 error with mutual SSL

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm trying to configure Artemis to allow connections using the CERT provided by the java client using the DN as the username. I have read almost all the documents and things I could find asking 'the google', but alas, I find myself at a frustrating stand-still.

I have the `acceptor` configured:

```xml
<acceptor name="netty=ssl-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:5500?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=xxxx;keyStorePassword=xxxx</acceptor>
```

And on client side I am passing the CERT (or at least I think I am). Here's the URL I'm using:

```
tcp://mynode:5500?sslEnabled=true;useDefaultSslContext=true
```

I have also used this URL:

```
tcp://mynode:5500?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=xxxx;keyStorePassword=xxxx
```

Without posting code (different network), can anyone provide any well-known issues or hints that might be causing the server to say:

```
Unable to validate user from /x.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx.  Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable
```

Comment: <acceptor name="netty=ssl-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:5500?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=xxxx;keyStorePassword=xxxx</acceptor>
URL is ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://mynode:5500?sslEnabled=true;useDefaultSslContext=true")
I have also used JNDI with
"tcp://mynode:5500?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=xxxx;keyStorePassword=xxxx"
I have also tested with trustStorePath, ect...
Works with security set to FALSE, but that is a given....

Answer (score 3):

The message you're seeing indicates that you're not passing any credentials when you connect (either username/password or SSL certificate). The reason you're not passing any credentials is because your `acceptor` configuration is incorrect since you're not telling clients to actually provide a certificate. You need to set `needClientAuth=true`, e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="netty=ssl-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:5500?sslEnabled=true;needClientAuth=true;keyStorePath=xxxx;keyStorePassword=xxxx</acceptor>
```

On the client, you should only use `useDefaultSslContext=true` if you're explicitly configuring the default SSL context (which is rare). You most likely should be using your second options where you configure `keyStorePath` and `keyStorePassword`.

Also, keep in mind that you'll need to either use certificates signed by a trusted authority or you'll need to create and configure trust stores on your client and broker and add the proper certificates to them.

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to set the Artemis user Preferences. Click profile account and select Preferences. If it empty, please fill out the default user first.
2. You need to add an extra acceptor configuration to disable the SSL. Open up `etc/broker.xml` and add following configuration.

   `<acceptor name="netty-ssl-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?sslEnabled=false</acceptor>`

Now it should work