# ActiveMQ Artemis mutual SSL issue

Tags: activemq-artemis

I run into the same issue described in [ActiveMQ Artemis AMQ229031 error with mutual SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66853779/activemq-artemis-amq229031-error-with-mutual-ssl).

Setup is done as per official example.

It looks there is something went wrong in the code. I was able to reproduce the mentioned issue.

Clients side says:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.1:47822. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: CN=ActiveMQ Artemis Client, OU=Artemis, O=ActiveMQ, L=AMQ, ST=AMQ, C=AMQ
```

Server side log file says:

```
021-06-22 06:27:49,209 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222216: Security problem while authenticating: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.1:47404. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: CN=ActiveMQ Artemis Client, OU=Artemis, O=ActiveMQ, L=AMQ, ST=AMQ, C=AMQ
```

I think Artemis finds the certificate, but it was unable to validate.

Comment: Please provide the contents of your `bootstrap.xml`, `login.config`, `cert-users.properties`, and `cert-roles.properties`. It looks like a bad configuration to me, but I can't say for sure without more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was bad configuration.

Comment: It was bad configuration and also one officiall referred jar file was missing, in release 2.0.18 it is shipped. We upgraded to release 2.0.18.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to release 2.18.0 solves the issue. It works fine now.